# When exactly is the canplaythrough event triggered in html5?

Tags: html, events, video, buffering, seek

In HTML5 a `canplaythrough` event is defined which is triggered when the whole video can play without stuttering (this is estimated by the browser). My question is, is this based on starting at the beginning of the video?

Let's say I do:

```
video.load();

video.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", function(){
    video.currentTime = 500;
}.bind(this), false );

video.addEventListener("canplaythrough", function(){
    console.log( "I can play through..." );
}.bind(this), false );
```

Will the `canplaythrough` event be triggered when the video can play through based on starting at the beginning or will it be triggered when the video can play through based on starting at the 500 seconds point of the video?

It may be the case that the first 20 seconds of video have been buffered which means that when played from the beginning it can play through, but when we then set the currentTime to 500 seconds then we might not be able to play through because this part hasn't been buffered yet.

Comment: I suspect you'll find that it is implementation specific.

Answer (score -2):

From the documentation:

> The canplaythrough event occurs when the browser estimates it can play through the specified audio/video without having to stop for buffering.

I'm assuming in order to estimate the result, the browser takes the download speed and overall file size into account.

Comment: You seem to have answered the question title without reading any of the body of the question which provides important context about what is being asked. As a result, this doesn't address the question at all.

Comment: My answer kind of clarifies that canplaytrough is an approximation, anything can happen to falsify the result after it was obtained.
I guess if one would want to know if the video is 100% buffered you should be using http://www.w3schools.com/tags/av_event_progress.asp

Comment: None of your comments seem remotely connected with the question, which is "Are the calculations for canplaytrough based on the point seeked to or the start?"

Comment: I answered the 2nd part of his question. (basically on how to deal with that)